# infix to postfix converstion in C with multiple digits input

Tags: c, algorithm, postfix-notation, infix-notation, shunting-yard

What I'm trying to obtain is a calculator that will take infix notation, ignore insignificant whitespace characters like " " or '@', then convert that infix notaion into postfix notation and do simple calculations like addition, subtraction etc. So far the code is taking input in infix notation trimming it in a way that ignores insignificant whitespace characters and outputs the postfix notation.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>;
#include <ctype.h>;

#define MAX_LENGTH  100

//Functions
void push(char x);
char pop();
void trimString(char string[], char newString[]);
void inputToRPN(char trimmedExp[], char rpnExp[]);
int calculateRPN(char rpnExp[]);


char stack[MAX_LENGTH];
char resStack[MAX_LENGTH];
int top = -1;
int resTop = -1;
int index = 0;

int main() {
    int res;

    char exp[MAX_LENGTH] = "10 +2";
    char trimmedExpression[MAX_LENGTH];
    char rpnExpression[MAX_LENGTH];

    // Input commented out as per suggestion in comments
    //printf("Enter expression : ");
    //fgets(exp, 100, stdin);
    printf("Infix expression: %s \n", exp);
    trimString(exp, trimmedExpression);
    printf("\n");
    inputToRPN(trimmedExpression, rpnExpression);
    res = calculateRPN(rpnExpression);

    //printf("Result of calculation: %d", res);
    return 0;
}

void push(char x) {
    stack[++top] = x;
}

char pop() {
    if (top == -1)
        return -1;
    else
        return stack[top--];
}

int priority(char x) {
    if (x == '(')
        return 0;
    if (x == '+' || x == '-')
        return 1;
    if (x == '*' || x == '/')
        return 2;
    return 0;
}

void trimString(char string[], char newString[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0' && string[i] != 10) {
        // Range of significant characters
        if (string[i] >= '(' && string[i] <= '9') {
            newString[j] = string[i];
            i++, j++;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    newString[j] = 0;
}

void inputToRPN(char trimmedExp[], char rpnExp[]) {
    char* e, x;
    e = trimmedExp;

    while (*e != '\0') {
        // Add to RPN if character is alphanumeric
        if (isalnum(*e)) {
            rpnExp[index] = *e;
            index++;
        }
        // Add to stack if is an open brace
        else if (*e == '(')
            push(*e);
        // Add all operators to the expression until finding open braces
        else if (*e == ')') {
            while ((x = pop()) != '(') {
                rpnExp[index] = x;
                index++;
            }
        }
        // If none of the above, that is an operator - check it's priority.
        // If it's priority is less that that of the one on top of the stack add the operator from the top of the stack to the expression; untill it's priority is higher.
        // At the end add current operator to the stack.
        else {
            while (priority(stack[top]) >= priority(*e)) {
                rpnExp[index] = pop();
                index++;
            }
            push(*e);
        }
        e++;
    }

    while (top != -1) {
        rpnExp[index] = pop();
        index++;
    }

    // Terminating character at the end of the string
    rpnExp[index] = 0;
}

void pushRes(char x) {
    printf("pushing: %c \n", x);
    resStack[++resTop] = x;
}

char popRes() {
    printf("poping \n");
    if (resTop == -1)
        return -1;
    else
        return resStack[resTop--];
}

int isValidOperator(char c) {
    if (c == '/' || c == '*' || c == '+' || c == '-')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int calculateRPN(char rpnExp[]) {
    // Doesnt do anything yet, just prints out the compiled reverse polish notation
    char* c;
    int result = 0;
    c = rpnExp;

    printf("Postfix expression: %s", rpnExp);

    return result;
}
```

The problem I've stumbled upon is when the infix input has multiple digits say 10+2 the code will treat each digit individually. Therefore the whole expression will be invalid when calculating result. I'm almost certain the issue lies in this line of code:

```
// Add to RPN if character is alphanumeric
if (isalnum(*e)) {
    rpnExp[index] = *e;
    index++;
}
```

Despite that I've got no idea how should i treat multiple digits while adding them to the expression, since the input is in form of character and there can be N amount of digits that have coresponding ascii values which range from 0-9. Looking forward to your answears.

Edit: made it so the code compiles and the input is hard coded.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. If you suspect that the problem is in function `inputToRPN`, I suggest to test this function only and omit all functions that are not required  for this test. Create a simple `main` function that feeds some (hard-coded) example input into `inputToRPN` and prints the output. Show the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: I'm unsure as to whether the problem is in `inputToRPN` function since I've seen examples of multiple digits being handled also in `push` function therefore I will leave entire code here so nothing is missing out. The code now compiles and has hardcoded example.

Comment: Function `inputToRPN` uses `push` and `pop`, so these must be present as well. You should have an idea what the function  `inputToRPN` is supposed to do. Write down a few example input strings and the expected output strings resulting from the input. (Did you write the code yourself? Or where did you get it from?)

Comment: I've wrote the algorithm myself based on basic rules of infix-postfix conversion, here are the rules used for the algorithm: https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-cpp/infix-to-postfix-conversion-program-in-c-using-stack-with-al/156

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the information from your comments there. The linked page shows an example of input and output. You could use this to test your function. Unfortunately the operands `ABC` are not separated in the output which would be a problem when an operand (like a number) can consist of multiple characters. Depending on how you want to implement the calculation, you could append a separator character after the numbers (or between numbers) or use an array of strings instead of an array of characters to allow storing numbers that consist of more than one digit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so thanks to Bodos suggestions I've fixed the issue. Adding one while loop in this section:

```
  if (isalnum(*e)) {
        rpnExp[index] = *e;
        index++;
    }
```

enabled me to add one character after every number (including the N digit ones).
Thanks to which I was later able to perform calculations in `calculateRPN` function that would eventually lead to correct answear.
The issue has been resolved.